# testing POST request in playframework

Tags: playframework

My controller method is something like this

```
public static void addItem(byte[] xmlFile) {
   ... //process file
}
```

and my ApplicationTest file

```
@Test
public void addItem() {
  Request request = newRequest();
  request.url = "/item";
  request.encoding = APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED;
  request.body = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlFileBytes)
  Response response = POST(request, "/item")
.....
}
```

When i run this i get exceptions .. with root cause
unsupported encoding: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

How does one resolve this...

Comment: found the answer but can't submit as I dont have enough reputation ... :)

Comment: The FunctionTest provide a POST method where one can submit a map of Files with a string key ...

    POST(java.lang.Object url, Map<String,String> parameters,Map<String,File> files)

    Sends a POST request to the application under tests as a multipart form.
My solution...
    Request request = newRequest();
    request.url = "/item";
    Map<String, String> paramMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    Map<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<String, File>();
    fileMap.put("xmlFile", new File("test/item.xml);
    Response response = POST("/item", paramMap, fileMap);
    assertIsOk(response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is one more case of not knowing APIs.... :)

The FunctionalTest provide a POST method where one can submit a map of Files with a string key ...

```
POST(java.lang.Object url, Map<String,String> parameters,Map<String,File> files)

Sends a POST request to the application under tests as a multipart form. Designed for file upload testing.
```

My Solution ...

```
Request request = newRequest();
request.url = "/item";
Map<String, String> paramMap = Maps.newHashMap();
Map<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<String, File>();
fileMap.put("xmlFile", new File("test/item.xml);
Response response = POST("/item", paramMap, fileMap);
assertIsOk(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way I handle this is by using "multipart/form-data" on the form and a File argument to the controller. That's also the documented way, as far as I know...

Comment: Could be. But then, I didn't see "GAE" in your question :)

Comment: sorry about that but I wanted to make my app generic... even with the multipart request type, i get the same error

Comment: strange. Does that just happen from a test or also from the browser? Full stack trace might be handy here to see who's throwing the error :)

Comment: works fine in the browser.. im trying to write tests and somehow can't get to post a file... if it works for you, can you just type in the code you use to test a POST request with a file as parameter of the controller method